# R: Simulation study of consensus voting

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

In this study, I am asking `nRaters` to vote on different response options (the probability they respond to different choices is defined by `ProbabilityDist` shown below). For each `item.i`, voting stops under two circumstances (whichever comes first):

1. Number of "votes" exceeds `AgreementThreshold` (i.e., percentage of people who agree on an item.
2. The maximum number of raters have answered the question (defined by `MaxNRaters`)

For example, voting stops if Rater1 and Rater2 respond "A" but continues if Rater1 responds "A" but Rater2 responds "B" (In this case, "A" should be returned if Rater3 responded with "A" because more than 50% was reached. But, "NoAgreement" should be returned if Rater3 responds with "C" - "H" since `AgreementThreshold` was not reached).

I've started the code below but I am stuck on how to create a loop or function that has a conditional stop in it. I would also like to have this repeat so that I can return output like the sample output show in `d.out`.

```
ResponseChoices= LETTERS[1:8]
ProbabilityDist= c(0.6, 0.2, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03)
MaxNRaters=3
AgreementThreshold = .5 
    #Obtain consensus answer when greater than 50% of raters agree 
    #e.g., if votes for Item.i = "A" "H" "A" return "A"

### Some kind of conditional loop here ###
### Note: the loop should iterate through multiple items using the stop rules described above

VotesForItem.i <- sample(ResponseChoices, nRaters, replace=TRUE, prob=ProbabilityDist)

##########################################


# return(votes)

#Sample of desired output
items=c(1:5)
VotedResponses=c("A","A","B","NoAgreement","A")
d.out=cbind(items,VotedResponses)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does what you ask for, albeit really slow for large values of `MaxNRaters`.

```
items <- 3    
responses <- c(8, 5, 4) # number of responses for each item
ResponseChoices <- lapply(1:items, function(i) paste0(LETTERS[1:responses[i]], i))
ProbabilityDist <- lapply(1:items, function(i)rmultinom(1, 100, prob = 1:responses[i])/100)

MaxNRaters=3
AgreementThreshold = .5
simResults=NULL
for(j in 1:items){
    i <- 1
    VotedResponses <- c()
    Rater <- c()
    decision <- c()
    while(i<=MaxNRaters){
        Rater <- c(Rater, i)

        resp <- sample(ResponseChoices[[j]], 1 , replace=TRUE, prob=ProbabilityDist[[j]])
        VotedResponses <- c(VotedResponses, resp)
        if(any(table(VotedResponses) > i*AgreementThreshold)&i>1) {
            decision <- c(decision, resp)
            break
        }
        else{
            decision <- c(decision, "No Agreement")
            i <- i+1
        }
    }
    nraters=length(decision)
    decision=decision[nraters]

    simResults.i=cbind(j, nraters,decision)

    simResults=rbind(simResults, simResults.i)
}
```

or something close to your desired output

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(responses=sample(ResponseChoices, 5, replace=TRUE, prob=ProbabilityDist))%>%
    group_by(responses) %>% mutate(counts=1:n()) %>% ungroup %>% 
    mutate(d= floor(row_number()*AgreementThreshold))%>%  
    mutate(decision=ifelse( cummax(counts) > d, responses, "NoAgreement"))%>% 
    select(-counts, -d)

#   responses    decision
#1         B           B
#2         A NoAgreement
#3         A           A
#4         A           A
#5         A           A
```

Voting stops at the first instance of non `NoAgreement` decision. In the example above, it stops at 3.

Comment: It's close... what are you defining as `i`? I was thinking it was the number of items but when I increase this above 3. I get a null result because `while(i<=MaxNRaters)` fails. The number of items should be independent of the number of raters.

Comment: As you see from `items <- c(items, i)`, it is `items`. It never goes beyond `MaxNRaters`.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? As it stands, `items i` means `ith Rater`, No?

Comment: Sorry I am not being clear. `MaxNRaters` is the maximum number of raters per item (e.g., only 3 raters can rate item 1). Whereas `items` is just the number of items in the questionnaire. EG if items = 10 there are 10 items and each can be rated by up to 3 people. `item.i` is just the i-th object. Does that make sense?

Comment: Edited slightly to clarify that we loop through Raters. `items` are predefined by `ResponseChoices`, and  its probabilities.

Comment: GOTCHA... ok this is close. Rather than return the votes and resulting decisions for each voters. Is it possible to return just the final decision and the number of voters it took to reach that decision for each `item.i`? That way, I could easily write an apply statement to do repeatedly for N items.

Comment: If you could give an instance of different number of `items`. I am not sure I got `for each item i` bit.

Comment: Just edited answer. Please see if this clarifies what i mean by `items`

Comment: Now I am even more puzzled about items.  I thought `items=ResponseChoices`.

Comment: No, think of it like a multiple choice test. Item 1 has response choices "A"..."B". Item 2 has the same response choices...as does the Nth item. I am interested in multiple people answering each question (or item) and seeing what answer they agree on. So, items should be independent of the number of raters.

Comment: I see. If each item has the same ResponseChoices and the same ProbabilityDist, your edit  achieves the desired result.

Comment: Right... for my purposes that's fine but I realize that's not the most realistic scenario.

Comment: I've updated to accommodate the varying ResponseChoices. HTH.